# Image Multiplication of Gray Image

Tags: c#, image-processing

When I process Image Multiplication of 2 Gray images, I do see color components. Not able to figure out what exactly is wrong here:

Image:
[image]
Reflected Image:
[image]
Image multiplication of above images:
[image]

Here is my function for Image Multiplicaiton:

```
public Bitmap MaskImage(Bitmap SrcBitmap1, Bitmap SrcBitmap2)
        {
            int width;
            int height;

            //Message = "Impossible.";

            if (SrcBitmap1.Width < SrcBitmap2.Width)
                width = SrcBitmap1.Width;
            else
                width = SrcBitmap2.Width;

            if (SrcBitmap1.Height < SrcBitmap2.Height)
                height = SrcBitmap1.Height;
            else
                height = SrcBitmap2.Height;

            Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(width, height);
            int clr1, clr2;

            try
            {
                BitmapData Src1Data = SrcBitmap1.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, SrcBitmap1.Width, SrcBitmap1.Height), ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, PixelFormat.Format8bppIndexed);

                BitmapData Src2Data = SrcBitmap2.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, SrcBitmap2.Width, SrcBitmap2.Height), ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, PixelFormat.Format8bppIndexed);

                BitmapData DestData = bitmap.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height), ImageLockMode.WriteOnly, PixelFormat.Format8bppIndexed);

                unsafe
                {
                    //Following is list of offset for different bit images
                    //8 bit : 1
                    //16 bit : 2
                    //24 bit : 3 and
                    //32 bit : 4
                    int xOffset = 1;

                    for (int col = 0; col < bitmap.Height - 1; col++)
                    {
                        byte* Src1Ptr = (byte*)Src1Data.Scan0 + col * Src1Data.Stride;
                        byte* Src2Ptr = (byte*)Src2Data.Scan0 + col * Src2Data.Stride;
                        byte* DestPtr = (byte*)DestData.Scan0 + col * DestData.Stride;

                        for (int row = 0; row < bitmap.Width - 1; row++)
                        {
                            clr1 = (Src1Ptr[row * xOffset] + Src1Ptr[row * xOffset + 1] + Src1Ptr[row * xOffset + 2]) / 3;
                            clr2 = (Src2Ptr[row * xOffset] + Src2Ptr[row * xOffset + 1] + Src2Ptr[row * xOffset + 2]) / 3;

                            clr1 *= clr2;

                            if (clr1 == 0)
                            {
                                DestPtr[row * xOffset] = (byte)(0);
                                DestPtr[row * xOffset + 1] = (byte)(0);
                                DestPtr[row * xOffset + 2] = (byte)(0);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                DestPtr[row * xOffset] = (byte)(Src2Ptr[row * xOffset]);
                                DestPtr[row * xOffset + 1] = (byte)(Src2Ptr[row * xOffset + 1]);
                                DestPtr[row * xOffset + 2] = (byte)(Src2Ptr[row * xOffset + 2]);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                bitmap.UnlockBits(DestData);
                SrcBitmap1.UnlockBits(Src1Data);
                SrcBitmap2.UnlockBits(Src2Data);

                SrcBitmap1.Dispose();
                SrcBitmap2.Dispose();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.Write(ex);
            }

            return bitmap;
        }
```

**EDIT:**

Based on Spektre code:

The problem still seems to be the same. Although I have tried to use intensity values instead of just color channels: below is the change in code: cant really figure out whats happening here.

Output:
[image]

```
public Bitmap MaskImage(Bitmap SrcBitmap1, Bitmap SrcBitmap2)
    {
        int width;
        int height;

        //Message = "Impossible.";

        if (SrcBitmap1.Width < SrcBitmap2.Width)
            width = SrcBitmap1.Width;
        else
            width = SrcBitmap2.Width;

        if (SrcBitmap1.Height < SrcBitmap2.Height)
            height = SrcBitmap1.Height;
        else
            height = SrcBitmap2.Height;

        Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(width, height);

        try
        {
            BitmapData Src1Data = SrcBitmap1.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, SrcBitmap1.Width, SrcBitmap1.Height), ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, PixelFormat.Format8bppIndexed);

            BitmapData Src2Data = SrcBitmap2.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, SrcBitmap2.Width, SrcBitmap2.Height), ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, PixelFormat.Format8bppIndexed);

            BitmapData DestData = bitmap.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height), ImageLockMode.WriteOnly, PixelFormat.Format8bppIndexed);

            unsafe
            {
                //Following is list of offset for different bit images
                //8 bit : 1
                //16 bit : 2
                //24 bit : 3 and
                //32 bit : 4
                int xOffset = 1;

                for (int col = 0; col < bitmap.Height - 1; col++)
                {
                    byte* Src1Ptr = (byte*)Src1Data.Scan0 + col * Src1Data.Stride;
                    byte* Src2Ptr = (byte*)Src2Data.Scan0 + col * Src2Data.Stride;
                    byte* DestPtr = (byte*)DestData.Scan0 + col * DestData.Stride;

                    for (int row = 0; row < bitmap.Width - 1; row++)
                    {
                        byte i1 = Src1Ptr[row * xOffset];
                        bbyte i2 = Src2Ptr[row * xOffset];
                        DestPtr[row * xOffset + 0] = (byte)((((ushort)(i1) * (ushort)(i2)) >> 8));
                        DestPtr[row * xOffset + 1] = (byte)((ushort)(((ushort)(i1) * (ushort)(i2)) >> 8));
                        DestPtr[row * xOffset + 2] = (byte)((ushort)(((ushort)(i1) * (ushort)(i2)) >> 8));
                    }
                }
            }

            bitmap.UnlockBits(DestData);
            SrcBitmap1.UnlockBits(Src1Data);
            SrcBitmap2.UnlockBits(Src2Data);

            SrcBitmap1.Dispose();
            SrcBitmap2.Dispose();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.Write(ex);
        }

        return bitmap;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some notes on your code:

Your image format is 8bpp already, so there's no RGB channels here:

```
clr1 = (Src1Ptr[row * xOffset] + Src1Ptr[row * xOffset + 1] + Src1Ptr[row * xOffset + 2]) / 3;
clr2 = (Src2Ptr[row * xOffset] + Src2Ptr[row * xOffset + 1] + Src2Ptr[row * xOffset + 2]) / 3;
```

so +1 and +2 are not required here, and the division of 3 to make the image gray. Because the input images are already gray-scaled images.

Also when assigning back the values to destination image, this should be sufficient:

```
DestPtr[row * xOffset] = (byte) //value of multiplied gray level
```

And on your sample you are just assigning back the values of the second image.

The resulting image why is it colored has to do with the shifting (offset, +1, and +2) as the image is not being written properly.

Comment: I understand now, another thing I dont understand is, I use ExtractChannel filter from Aforge for Green channel extraction, on analysing the data in Mathematica, it says the image dimensions is 2592x1944x3 where 2592x1944 is the image resolution, but why 3? Isnt a channel extract supposed to give only one 2D array of imagedata ?

Comment: The Aforge's Imaging Library's ExtractChannel accepts 24, 32, 48 and 64bpp pixel formats and outputs 8bpp or 16bpp. How did you save the data before analysing in Mathematica?  If you save the data in 24bpp format then it would be WxHx3 (for 24-bit). But if you save the image in 8bpp then it would be WxHx1 (for 8-bit).

Comment: I still get the same result following the suggestion.

Comment: I just saved the image after channel extract as follows: ExtractChannel GreenChannel = new ExtractChannel(RGB.G);//Extract G-Channel //
                    Bitmap ChannelImage = GreenChannel.Apply(image);//For thresold & Blob calculation//
                    Bitmap GChannel = GreenChannel.Apply(image);// For picbox1.//
                    GChannel.Save("C:\\Users\\MaximusDecimus\\Desktop\\GChannel.bmp");

Comment: Could you check the GChannel.bmp properties from the Windows explorer? It should be 8-bit.

Comment: I did; it says 8bpp format, and I save it as a file and import it to Mathematica and see the dimensions and it shows 3. This is what I am confused about.

Answer (score 0):

Joel Legaspi Enriquez is right I just want to add

- you need to multiply intensities not colors
- gray scale encoded as color in RGB is when `R==G==B`
- that is why you need just single component
- when you multiply `rgb1*rgb2` you got `(3*8 + 3*8 bit result)`
- which is a big number with many overflows between RGB channels
- that is the reason for colors appearing from nowhere

To remedy that:

1. multiply just intensities

   - so just single channel does not matter which one from `r,g,b`
2. normalize output range back to original bit count

   - so each channel is usually 8 bits
   - after multiply it is 16 bits
   - so just divide by (1^8) which is 256 or bit shift right by 8 bits
   - and then copy result to all channels

     ```
     BYTE i1=Src1Ptr[row * xOffset];
     BYTE i2=Src2Ptr[row * xOffset];
     DestPtr[row * xOffset+0] = BYTE(WORD((WORD(i1)*WORD(i2))>>8));
     DestPtr[row * xOffset+1] = BYTE(WORD((WORD(i1)*WORD(i2))>>8));
     DestPtr[row * xOffset+2] = BYTE(WORD((WORD(i1)*WORD(i2))>>8));
     ```

[edit1]

the address computation of yours looks suspicious

- I tought it was encapsulated in the `xOffset` somehow and did not look further
- but on second look you set ti to 1 and you do not apply the y offset anywhere I can see
- I would compute address of pixel(x,y) like `address = (x*Stride)+(y*Width*stride)`
- may be I am looking wrongly at your code but it looks like
- you have also mixed `col` and `row`
- bitmaps are stored as lines(rows) not columns
- so the `for`s should be swapped
- the outer loop should be `y` (row) and the inner `x` (col)

Comment: Thank you for explaining my fault, however even after the suggestions I am not able to get a gray image for ImageMask function. I have edited the question with changes from your suggestion. I guess I am doing something wrong here.

Comment: Did you mean: byte i2 = Src2Ptr[row * xOffset];

Comment: @abhilashsukumari yes of coarse ... copy paste typo already edited

Comment: @abhilashsukumari after reading edit of yours I probably discover the source of your problem see [edit1] in my answer